# When making changes to HTML or CSS, they are not visible on the page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, caching

When I make changes to my web page, the end user can not see the update until it clears the browser cache, uses the incognito mode, etc.

There will be some solution so that when making changes in HTML or CSS these are reflected immediately upon entering the web without needing to Clean Cache, enter Incognito Mode, use the Network / Disbled Cache of google chrome (which does not work most of the times) or install an extension to clean the cache ??

Comment: Hello KrmX! If my answer solved your issue please feel free to accept it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can version your CSS and JavaScript source files to prevent the user from having to clear cache each time you make an update. Just add on `?v=` on the end of your filename and include the version number.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=12345678" />
```

Comment: It is difficult to change the version to all files every time I want to update the page, and more in the development stage.

What I did was change from .html to .php and add the following at the end: " ?v=<?php echo time() ?> "

Comment: Applied to your example, it would look like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=<?php echo time() ?>" />

Comment: What I did to solve the problem was convert mi html file to php file, add  `?v=` in each Javascript and CSS file and call the time() function with PHP, for example: `<script src="js/file.js?v=<?php echo time() ?>"></script>` then I get a new version of the file on every update of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to force a cache reload when refreshing the page.

[Wikipedia:Bypass your cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache)